# protecting cells with google apps script (with dynamic button or command)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

does anyone know if it is possible to make a google apps script for a google spreadsheet, that protects particular cells if a given situation occurs? 
Fx. if an X occurs in "A1", then "A2" should be protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to manage cell protection yet. This [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721) asks for this. You may want to *star* it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not. I don't believe that's the way that cell protection works. A cell is manually protected, or not protected at all.

There is no cell function or Script Object that enables that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The "feature request" [referred by Henrique G. Abreu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286398/1595451) was fixed. Reference [comment #165](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756264#comment165)

> Today, we have launched the ability to programmatically create and
>   manipulate protected ranges and protected sheets with Apps Script.
>
> With the new Protection class in the Spreadsheet service, your scripts
>   can touch every aspect of range or sheet protection, just like in the
>   new UI. (The older PageProtection class, which had more limited
>   features, will be deprecated, but will stick around in case you need
>   to work with older spreadsheets. The new Protection class only applies
>   to the newer version of Sheets.)
>
> You can find more details here:
>
> http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/02/control-protected-ranges-and-sheets-in.html
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#february_2015
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Answer (score 0):

i know that this is an old question and still - google "feture request" (posted by Henrique Abreu) has no progrees till now (end of 2014)

**my hunch:** this kind of feature would be a workaround for google forms (http://www.google.com/forms/about) when users are requested to edit cells that getting locked afterwards (by a criteria or another kind of logic)

i recently came accross a similar situation at my workplace, and my solution is very simple - make a form and share it with relevant users. the form fields will enable users to fill up the data they should be locked. that form will end up generating a sheet of information (updated online each time a form is filled). using "**IMPORTRANGE**" (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) from another sheet will result in querying the "locked" information inside your relevant sheet. since the data is inside another sheet and is represented as a formula - it cannot be edited (at least not as a data)

i really considering a true workaround which can actually "lock" a cell (by replacing its value to the original by a script).. if there is such a request

Answer (score -2):

I have a work-around, code follows

```js
function protect_named_range(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//change "sheet1" for the sheet your range is in
  var array_range1 = target_sheet.getRange("A1:A1");
  var array_range2 = target_sheet.getRange("A2:A2");
  var range_test = array_range1.getValue();// or getFormula or what ever you want to test
  if(range_test == "correct answer"){ //if cell A2 = "correct answer" then cell B2 becomes a named range called "named_range"       
    ss.setNamedRange("named_range", array_range2);
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(target_sheet);
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
   permissions.setProtected(true);
   target_sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);
  }
 }
```

Sorry I have been away for awhile.  This is the basic code I would use, however it doesnt actually protect the range "B2" if cell A2 = "correct answer. instead it protects the sheet named "sheet1" if cell A2 = "correct answer" so that only the spreadsheet owner may edit anything on the sheet.

I know this isnt exactly what your after, but I hope it can help.

Comment: Cool - will you be able to complete it?

Comment: Please :D it would be nice if you could finish the code - it looks brilliant so far!

Comment: This is for protecting a whole sheet, not a group of Cells.

Comment: -1, as stated by @eddyparkinson the question is about cell protection not sheet protection